# Redirect directories to subfolder with the same structure

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect 
http://www.example.com/banners  to
http://resources.example.com/banners

I want all the files in  the directories/banners to redirect to the sub domain with /banners and with the same  files structure .

regards,
John

Comment: are u using apache? iis?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/banners
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^resources.example.com
RewriteRule ^banners http://resources.example.com/banners [R=301,L]
```